# Function syntax error in PHP

Tags: php, function

Does anyone know this PHP function syntax and how it works? It's not working with PHP 5.5

```
    public function getProxiesTargetDir() : string
    {
        return $this->proxiesTargetDir ?: $this->proxiesTargetDir = sys_get_temp_dir();
    }
```

Comment: `getSomething() { /* Do stuff here */ }`

Comment: that requires a class to run with, seeing "public".

Comment: I know that guys, but a external library have this sintaxis. See the edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using typed returns `public function getProxiesTargetDir() : string` which [only exists starting from PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.return-type-declarations).

For previous versions just remove `: string` > `public function getProxiesTargetDir() {}`

Comment: And if it's an external library, you'll need to use an older PHP5-compatible version of it.

Answer (score -1):

You are using the shorthand if/else syntax of PHP here, but let's use the long way:

```
public function getProxiesTargetDir()
{
    if( $this->proxiesTargetDir ==  false ){
           return ( $this->proxiesTargetDir = sys_get_temp_dir() );
    }
    else{ 
          return $this->proxiesTargetDir;
   }
}
```

If have also deleted the `:string`, because it can make errors and it is not really necessary here.